# canvas.todataurl() not working in android 2.3.3

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, canvas, cordova

I am drawing an 3 images on canvas and saving base64 to database, and retriving that value and displaying it in my page.

`canvas.todataurl()` works in my android 4.2.2 version

But when i tried to work on 2.3.3 instead of image i am getting just a question mark.

```
var canvasimage = document.getElementById('ImageDisplay');
     var context = canvasimage.getContext('2d');
   Image = canvas.toDataUrl();
```

How to solve this?

Thanks:)

Comment: toDataURL()... NOT todataurl()

Comment: @cocco typo error. sorry:)

Comment: and Image?? Image.src=canvas.toDataUrl();

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/

Comment: just saving canvas.toDataUrl to one variable for using it later purpose

Comment: no support on old versions.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done this way:

## Working sample

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
context.drawImage(img, X, Y); //draws canvas image in X, Y
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vixing/mHd4b/ <-- example